# How to fix this error with TabRowDefaults in Jetpack Compose (material3)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have one problem with TabRow in Jetpack Compose, here's the code's fragment:

```
TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = tabIndex,
            indicator = { pos ->
                TabRowDefaults.Indicator(Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, pos))
            },
        ){
            tabList.forEachIndexed{index, text ->
                Tab(selected = false, onClick = {
                                                coroutineScope.launch{
                                                    pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                                                }
                }, text = {
                    Text(text = text)
                })
            }
        }
```

The thing is, the parameter "pos" here is underlined in red ([image: see the image here]). I don't know why, it's written "Type mismatch: inferred type is List<androidx.compose.material3.TabPosition> but List<androidx.compose.material.TabPosition> was expected".

I tried to remove "pos" and replace it with "it", also I tried in "import TabRowDefaults" to replace material3 with material. How to fix this error?

Comment: The error is clear, you are importing the Material TabPosition, not the material3 TabPosition.

Comment: What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
import androidx.compose.material3.TabRow
import androidx.compose.material3.TabRowDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.TabRowDefaults.tabIndicatorOffset

TabRow(
    selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex,
    modifier = modifier,
    containerColor = Color.Transparent,
    contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
    indicator = { tabPositions ->
        TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
            modifier = Modifier.tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[selectedTabIndex]),
            height = 2.dp,
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
        )
    },
    tabs = {
      ...
    }
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help, but I tried to do like this:


```
TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = tabIndex,
            containerColor = Blue1,
            contentColor = Blue1,
            indicator = { tabPositions ->
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                TabRowDefaults.Indicator(modifier = Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState, tabPositions as List<androidx.compose.material.TabPosition>),
                color = Color.White)
            }
        )
```

Comment: The error disappeared, but when I launched this app on my phone, it crashed. I opened Logcat and saw it:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.c_weatherapp, PID: 27109
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.compose.material3.TabPosition cannot be cast to androidx.compose.material.TabPosition

Comment: both of Tab and TabRow  should import from androidx.compose.material3
check your imports and fix all of them

Comment: i edit the answer and write the correct imports

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace the accopanist -pager library with the latest version